# Split app does not call view when item selected second time

Tags: sapui5

I have a splitapp, that shall run on a mobile device. When I click on an item from my ActionItemList, the screen flips and the view is shown. This works well with different items in the ActionItemList.

My problem is, that when I choose twice the same item from my ActionItemList, the second call does not work. This is actually no problem when the app runs on a laptop because everything is shown side by side, but when it runs on a mobile I see either the ActionItemList or the selected view. So in that case the screen with the ActionItemList will only disappear if I call another view and then call the view again, I actually wanted.

Here some information of coding:

Masterview:

```
<List>
    <items>
        <ActionListItem id="umlagId" text="Umlagerung" press="Umlag" class="color"/>
        <ActionListItem id="kdx" text="Kardexmonitor" press="kdx01" class="color"/>
        <ActionListItem id="kdx2" text="Materialbereitstellung" press="kdx02" class="color"/>
    </items>
</List>
```

Mastercontroller

```
Umlag: function () {
            this.getRouter().navTo("umlagerung");
        },
kdx01: function () {
            this.getRouter().navTo("kardex01");
        },
kdx02: function () {
            this.getRouter().navTo("kardex02");
```

And here part of the view:

```
<Page title="Umlagerung" showNavButton="{device>/isPhone}" navButtonPress="handleNavButtonPress">
```

and the controller:

```
handleNavButtonPress: function () {
    var oSplitApp = this.getView().getParent().getParent();
    var oMaster = oSplitApp.getMasterPages()[0];
    oSplitApp.toMaster(oMaster, "flip");
},
```

I guess, I need to close the current view after chosing another? But I don't know where I can do this, because I don't find any event that runs on closing the view.

Many thanks in advance and best regards
Julia

Comment: Did you check:

onExit()
This method is called on the destruction of the View.

Comment: Is your button press handler triggered? Also have you compared your code with the available samples? https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/entity/sap.m.SplitApp/sample/sap.m.sample.SplitApp/code/C.controller.js

Comment: Did you remove part of your code before posting here? It's important that your List has `mode="None"` on mobile devices (which is the default) so it doesn't store which item was selected. This way you can click on the same item endlessly.